# Why my tensorflow example code training result is increasing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Hi I am learning tensorflow.
This is my code, a simple multivariable tensorflow example.
Running environment is Python3.5.3, Tensorflow 0.12.1, Windows7.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data & output data
x1_data = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 5.0]
x2_data = [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y_data =  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

# W1, W2, b random generation
# W1 = 1, W2 = 1, b = 0 is ideal
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))

# Our hypothesis
hypothesis = W1 * x1_data + W2 * x2_data + b
# Simplified cost function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - y_data))

# Minimize
a = tf.Variable(0.1) # Learning Rate
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(a)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

# Initialise
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Train loop
for step in range(10):
    sess.run(train)
    print(step, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W1), sess.run(W2), sess.run(b))
```

I expected the result will decrease as training loops.

but it increases infinitely.

Same code on one variable worked well and it decreased.

I don't know why 2-variable increases...

```
0 52.0504 [ 1.47101164] [ 2.24049234] [ 0.86718893]
1 157.129 [-1.74108529] [-1.84496927] [-0.22162986]
2 478.055 [ 4.02118969] [ 5.11457825] [ 1.86127353]
3 1457.33 [-5.99311352] [-7.13181305] [-1.60902405]
4 4445.18 [ 11.50830746] [ 14.20653534] [ 4.60829926]
5 13561.2 [-19.06884766] [-23.10119247] [-6.10722733]
6 41374.3 [ 34.32733154] [ 42.03698349] [ 12.74352837]
7 126232.0 [-58.95558929] [-71.76408386] [-20.05929375]
8 385134.0 [ 103.96767426] [ 126.9929657] [ 37.3527832]
9 1.17505e+06 [-180.62704468] [-220.19728088] [-62.82305145]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I've found was to decrease the learning rate to 0.01. It seems like the steps are changing your parameters too radically. Probably if you'd use some kind of a regularization technique (Like L2) this wouldn't happen.

Second, your code need some refinement. Use tensorflow matrix operations and initialize the bias with zero. Strangely when using TF functions for operations even the 0.1 learning rate is okay.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Input data & output data
x1_data = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 5.0]
x2_data = [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y_data =  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

input_X = tf.Variable(np.row_stack((x1_data, x2_data)).astype(np.float32))
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,2], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))

# Our hypothesis
hypothesis = tf.add(tf.matmul(W,input_X),b)
# Simplified cost function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - y_data))

# Minimize
a = tf.Variable(0.1) # Learning Rate
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(a)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

# Initialise
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Train loop
for step in range(10):
    sess.run(train)
    print(step, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```